# ¿cómo puedo pasar un valor a otra pagina en php sin mostrar por url?

Tags: php, sql

el problema es que al pasar el valor a la otra ventana lo pasa mediante la url, y si solo lo paso con metodo post envia el ultimo id de la tabla

```
<script>
function Eliminar(id){
    location='eliminar_cliente.php?id_cliente='+id;
}
function Editar(id){
    location='editar_cliente.php?id_cliente='+id;
}
</script>

<?php
include ("Cliente.php");
echo "<form name='f1' id='f1' method='POST' action='editar_cliente.php'>";
echo "<table align='center'  border='2' class='table table-hover'>";
        echo"<tr  border='2'>";
            echo"<td align='center'><label for='rut'>Id Cliente</label></td>";
            echo"<td align='center'><label for='nombre'>Raz&oacute;n Social</label></td>";
            echo"<td align='center'><label for='dire'>RUT</label></td>";
            echo"<td align='center'></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
                    $A = new Cliente();
                    foreach ($A->Todos() as $tmp)
                    {
                        echo"<tbody id='tabla'>";
                        echo"<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$tmp->id."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$tmp->razon."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$tmp->rut."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'> <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$tmp->id."' > <input type='button'  name='btn' value='Editar' onclick=\"Editar('".$tmp->id."')\"> ";
                        echo "<input type='button'  name='btn' class='btn btn-danger' value='Eliminar' onclick=\"Eliminar('".$tmp->id."')\">";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo"</tbody>";
                    }       
echo"</table>";
echo "</form>";
?> 



<!-- PAGINA editar_cliente.php--->

<?php
include("Cliente.php");
$E = new Cliente();
$E->getCliente($_GET['id_cliente']);

?>
```

Comment: El problema es que todos los inputs tienen el mismo name `pid`.  Intenta ponerles nombres diferentes concatenando un contador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personalmente eliminaría el script del principio que inyecta las rutas y el id. Quitaría la apertura del formulario al principio de la tabla y prepararía dos formularios, uno dentro de cada celda, para cada caso respectivamente pasando el valor del id en un input oculto. Por ejemplo:

```
echo "<td align='center'>"
   + "<form method='post' action='editar_cliente.php'>"
      + "<input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$tmp->id."' >" 
      + "<input type='button'  name='btn' value='Editar'>"
   + "</form>"
+ "</td>";
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo.